# How to make a Salesforce page display more fields?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm new to Salesforce and try to create a new custom object on Salesforce called "AccountAudit".
I create fields for this object and want to display some of them on the page.
However, the default page displays only "AccountAudit Name".

Is there anywhere that I can set to display more fields like "Last modified by", etc?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a setting icon after the search box. Create a new List view.
Refer this below link,
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_lex.htm&type=5